# Problems using extract() function to insert arguments into class method directly

Tags: php, methods, parameter-passing

Is this possible Im trying to do this with the extract() function since Im unable to get the method arguments in advance

```
class Test{
    public function getData($id){
       //use $id here
    }
}

$class = 'Test'; //this is determined dymanically
$method = 'getData'; //this is also determined dynamically
$arguments = ['id'=>'1234'];

$test = new $class();
$test->{$method}(extract($arguments));
```

> //this generates a warning Missing argument 1 for Test::getData(),
>   called

How can this be implemented?

EDIT
It appears I've simplified it too much, the code is intended to be the main deployment mechanism in a mini-framework Im developing so the method - getData is determined dynamically and therefore I cant know the arguments for each method in advance.
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? It doesn't seem to make sense to pass the return value from extract to your function. I don't see any reason that would throw a warning though. Show real code, and tell us what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found the solution using ReflectionMethod

```
    $reflection = new \ReflectionMethod('Test', 'getData');

   $pass = [];
   foreach($reflection->getParameters() as $param){

       //parse the method to get its arguments and filter through the sent arguments array
       if(isset($args[$param->getName()])){

           //check if the arguments exists and select them
           $pass[] = $args[$param->getName()];
      }
      else{

           $pass[] = $param->getDefaultValue();
      }
   } 

   //execute the resolved parameters
   return $reflection->invokeArgs(new Test, $pass);
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to make sense at all in the context you gave. Why not simply passing your array?

Comment: @Eiko - Ive made a few edits to the original question and added more context. Also read some of my commentary

Answer (score 0):

`extract` is for assigning to variables. For each element of the associative array, it will assign to a variable in the current scope with that name. It returns the number of variables it assigned, not the value of any of the variables.

There's no reason to use `extract` in your case, just get the element of the array that you want:

```
$test->getData($arguments['id']);
```

I'm not sure why you're getting an error about a missing argument. It should pass `1` as the `$id` argument, since there's one element in the array.

If you don't know which elements the function needs, a better design would be to pass the whole `$arguments` array to the function, and let it use the parts it wants.

```
public function getData($args) {
    $id = $args['id'];
    // Use $id
}

...

$test->getData($arguments);
```

Comment: The example is a simplification I cannot do this directly because the method and its arguments are determined dynamically. And I have seen what you mean. Is there a function which does something similar??

Comment: You need to edit the question to explain what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Maybe you should pass `$arguments` to the function, and let it take the elements that it wants from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just `extract` your array and pass `$id`

```
<?php
class Test{
    public function getData($id){
       echo $id;
    }
}

$arguments = array('id'=>'1234');
extract($arguments);
$test = new Test();
$test->getData($id);
```

or

```
$arguments = array('id'=>'1234');
extract($arguments);
$test = new Test();
foreach($arguments as  $key=>$value){
    $test->getData($$key); 

    }
```